# Deciding whether sets of Godel's number is recursive.

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

let $\alpha$ be a sentence (closed formula) in number theory language, such that $PA\nvdash\neg\alpha$. For any sentence $\beta$ , let us denote $g(\beta)$ as $\beta$'s Godel number. We define the next sets:

$S= \{ g(\beta) : PA \vdash \alpha \rightarrow\beta \}$

$T= \{ g(\beta) : PA \vdash \beta \rightarrow\alpha \}$

$T\cup S$

When $PA$ denotes Peano's axioms.
I wish to demonstrate that $S,T,S\cup T$ are not recursive.

For S: One can use deduction theorem: $S= \{ g(\beta) : PA\cup \alpha \vdash \beta \}$, we know that $PA\nvdash \neg\alpha$ so $PA\cup\alpha$ is consistent, therefore $PA\cup \alpha$ is not complete by Godel's theorem, so there is a formula $\gamma$ such that $PA\cup\alpha \nvdash \gamma$ and $PA\cup\alpha \nvdash \neg\gamma$ .

Another approach, is using the fact that $cons(PA)$ is not recursive, maybe we may assume that $cons(PA\cup\alpha)$ is recursive, and by that defining an algorithm (we accept Church thesis) to construct an algorithm which determines for every $\gamma$ whether $\gamma \in cons(PA)$ which contradicts $PA$ undecidability?

Comment: What you did for $S$ does not prove that $S$ is not recursive... and what do you mean, $cons(PA)$ is no recursive ? $cons(PA)$ is a single sentence

Comment: $cons(PA) = \{\alpha : PA \vdash \alpha \}$ when $\alpha$ is a sentence.

Comment: If $PA\vdash \alpha$, then $T$ consists of all Gödel numbers for wffs, so $T$ and $T\cup S$ are certainly recursive then.

Comment: You got off to a good start by using the deduction theorem, but then got sidetracked into (in)completeness versus (non)recursiveness. $S$ is the set of Gödel numbers of theorems of PA$+\alpha$, which is a consistent extension of PA. Therefore $S$ is not recursive.